# Spring bean overiding bug/feature

Tags: spring, javabeans, overriding

Recently i came across a "strange" Spring behaviour which i do not know if it is the expected behavior or a bug.

I have two spring files:

FileA.xml

```
<bean id="AbstractParent" class="com.classes.MyAbstractClass" abstract="true"/>    
<bean id="ConcreateChild parent="AbstractParent" />
```

FileB.xml

```
<import resource="FileA.xml"/>
<bean id="AnotherChild" parent="AbstractParent" />
<bean id="ConcreateChild" parent="AnotherChild"/>
```

I also have two different objects(which implement BeanNameAware) that have a reference to "ConcreateChild". I was expecting that both objects will have a reference to the same ConcreateChild object. But this is not the case.

When i debug and try to see the BeanName one reference is giving me "ConcreateChild" (as expected) but the other "AnotherChild".

Does anyone know if this is expected? I would expect the same reference to "ConcreateChild" always.

Couldn't find any answers or explanation in Spring documentation thus i posted here.

Thanks.

Comment: You have defined 3 instances in your xml. But two of them have the SAME id (`ConcreateChild`), and for the first an `"` is missing. I think you have done some mistake while posting the question, you should first correct the xml in your question.

Comment: Hi Ralph, yes a quote is missing as i wrote the xml in stackoverflow to simplify my situation. Could you please refer to my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss understand the concept of parent and abstract in Spring.

When you define a bean with abstract="true", it will not create an instance of it. It will only create the bean definition with the id defined.

On the other hand when you use parent attribute for a particular bean, it will create an instance of that bean with information defined within the parent's definition plus the definition that is defined within its own bean. Of course if there are some conflicting properties set, the child will win.

In your case, the first ConcreateChild is the result of an instance created with information from AbstractParent. But the second one is the result of an instance created with information from AnotherChild, which was also created using information from Abstract Parent.

So in this case you actually have 3 instances of same bean which are created using AbstractParent's bean definition.

Comment: Hello Wins, could you please refer to my anser above, as it was too long for a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

However i am a bit confused. First of all i don't understand why 3 instances will be created. I though 2 instances will be created from my xml files. I thought in Spring if you do not specify the 'scope' of a bean it is 'singleton' by default. Thus i would expect two objects to be created one for id="AnotherChild" and one for id="ConcreateChild". I wouldn't expect two instances of "ConcreateChild".

In addition about my question imagine i have the next two beans in my configuration:

```
<bean id="Primary" class="ImplementingClass">
<property name="AbstractParent" ref="ConcreateChild" />
</bean>


<bean id="Secondary" class="ImplementingClass">
<property name="AbstractParent" ref="ConcreateChild" />
</bean>
```

The above two beans are not created one after the other, but they both referencing "ConcreateChild" object. When i look for the instance of that object in one case it is "ConcreateChild" and in the other case it is "AnotherChild". This is actually what i do not understand. I would expect the instance of the object to be the same in both beans, or at least both of them to have "ConcreateChild" as id.

If you need any further explanation please let me know.

Comment: if you have a new question then create a new stack overflow question, if you have additional information for one of your question, then update your question instead of abusing the answer function.

Comment: Anyway: Singleton scope in context of spring mean, than if you inject a bean reference or use something like `MyBean myobj=(MyBean)context.getBean("myBean");` you will get always the same bean. If you define two beans of the same class they then singleton scope does NOT mean that they will become the same bean by some magic. Therefore you have different instances/beans of the same class.

Comment: Does it seem like a new questions to you? Because to me seems like a clarification in another answer. I would like to add it as comment to a previous answer but it was too long that's why i added as an answer.

Comment: no need to get pissed. And yes it, sounds more like a question "First of all i don't understand why 3 instances will be created. I though 2 instances will be created from my xml files...", "...Could you please refer to my below answer?" or an enhancement of your question "If you need any further explanation please let me know." than an straight answer. (Something that explain why it is).  -- Anyway I hope my comment above explain the singleton scope stuff a bit.

Comment: If i define two beans with the same id (like i do in my initial question), are they going to be two different instances or only one? This is one part of my question.

The other is if the objects above (Primary and Secondary) should have the same reference to ConcreateChild or different references. As i told before AbstractParent implements BeanNameAware, so i can see the id on those objects. I would expect the id to be ConcreateChild in both of them, but in one is "AnotherChild" which is what confuses me as i dont do ref="AnotherChild" nowher in the code.

Comment: For this special case have a look at this stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443070/same-bean-id-on-different-xml-file-will-it-merge

Comment: @nikkatsa For each bean defined in the xml, behind the scene, there will be a BeanDefinition object created. The scope attribute is used to determine whether the container will create a new object based on the definition or reusing the existing one when the client (application) request that object.